# NGINX - How to redirect on 504 gateway timeout

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, timeout

I'm using NGINX as a reverse proxy to a glassfish. When the glassfish returns 50x errors, I'm able to identify and redirect to another resource from a cdn.

But if it simply times out, NGINX will respond to the user with 504 gateway timeout instead of redirecting to a good resource at the CDN through rewrite.

I'd like to do the same thing in this case, if NGINX times out, I want to redirect to another URL, the same way I do in @redir_404 .

How can I achieve that?

Thank you.

```
server {
listen *:80;
ssl off;

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access-.log;
error_log   /var/log/nginx/error-.log;

client_max_body_size 60m;

location @redir_404 {
    rewrite /ad/(.*?)(\?.*)?$ $scheme://cdn.company.com/ad/$1/index.html break;
    rewrite /tag(.*?)$  $scheme://cdn.company.com/tag/pixel.png break;
}

location / {
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    set_real_ip_from 192.23.45.16;
    real_ip_recursive on;
    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;

    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;

    # Force timeouts if one of the backend is dead #
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;    

    # Set headers #
    proxy_set_header    Host        $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header        X-Umotion-Ip    $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        User-Agent    $http_user_agent;

    add_header      Front-End-Https on; 

    # By default we don't want to redirect #
    proxy_redirect off;

    # Force cache-control to no-cache for /tag and /ad
    location ~ ^/(tag|ad) {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        add_header Cache-Control "private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    }

    error_page 403 404 405 500 501 502 503 504 = @redir_404;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Add error_page location to redirect  within your server block.

```
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        internal;
  }
```

We can customise the error pages as required(/50x.html is cutom designed page)

Comment: There is already a error_page directive, but under location /. Are you saying that if I put this directive under server instead it will solve the problem of intercepting 504 gateway timeout?

Comment: If you use internal then the 50x.html can't be displayed, you just marked as for internal use only. It will return 404.